# What's wrong with my Python code ( simulating POW(x,y))

Tags: python

I am practicing recursion, and try to similuating pow(x,y).

Here is my code:

```
def power(x,y):
    for y in range(1,y):
        return x * power(x,y)
```

why it got :

> > > power(2,3)
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >           power(2,3)
> > >         File "C:/Python34/1.py", line 3, in power
> > >           return x * power(x,y)
> > >       TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Comment: As a hint: `for` is a purely iterative construct, so it's not the key to a recursive function. When you use a recursive function, you generally call it again with slightly different parameters - in your case, a different `y`. You also need a "base case" - what will happen when you hit the innermost level of recursion? What will you return?

Comment: You're using a loop AND recursion - you need to pick one!

Comment: @Brionius: Except when you want to loop and `yield` recursively, which (unlike returning in a loop) makes sense, and often necessary in pre-3.3 Python to simulate `yield from`… But yeah, otherwise, completely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be mixing iteration with recursion.

You also have a confusing variable shadowing with `y`.

Here is a purely recursive solution:

```
def power(x,y):
    if y == 0: return 1
    return x * power(x, y-1)
```

Here is a purely iterative solution:

```
def power(x,y):
    v = 1
    for i in range(0,y):
       v *= x
    return v
```

Answer (score 2):

When function skip (or finish) `for` loop it ends its job with default value `None`
so sometimes you have `return x * None` in place of `return x * power(x,y)`

Your function is for Python like

```
def power(x,y):
    for y in range(1,y):
        return x * power(x,y)
    return None
```

---

BTW: using `return` inside `for` loop does not make sense. First `return` will finish `for` loop.

`return X` means `end function at once and return value X`

Comment: The "BTW" part is a nice explanation of what exactly he's doing wrong with his mixing-iteration-and-recursion.

Comment: I think people sometimes treat `return` like in Pascal. In Pascal in function you can set returned value in any moment but only last line ends execution of function.

Comment: Good insight. Some Basics work similarly too. I've never made that connection, but it explains why at least some people write things like this.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `range(1,1)` is an empty set.

If the `for` loop is given an empty set, you'll skip the `return` statement.

If the return statement is skipped, a function will return `None`.

The first time you recurse you call the function with `y=1` which triggers the first condition.

P.S. This is not the only thing wrong with your program.

Answer (score 0):

When `y` is equal to 1 then your function returns `None`